# How to handle error when writing stored procedure or reading store procedure in spring

Tags: java, mysql

How do we handle error condition  while writing stored procedure or accessing stored procedure from java?

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the stored procedure, it will return error code if some of the operation has failed. You should put a try and catch block for the code. Catching SQLException is one of the way if the stored procedure itself fail.